# Newrelic - Setting Availability Monitoring URL via API

Tags: api, monitoring, newrelic

Is there a way to set the URL that Newrelic pings to monitor the availability, using its API? 
A bash command to achieve this will be extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this via the REST API (V1 or V2).  You can [enable/disable](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/apis/api-v2-examples/availability-monitoring-examples-api-v2#enable_disable) Availability Monitoring or [change the thresholds](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/apis/api-v2-examples/availability-monitoring-examples-api-v2#Resetting-availability-monitor-parameters), however.